# Rigify doesn't generate my rig correctly

Tags: armature, rigify

[image]

When I press the generate rig button, only the jaw is create properly , the others are just like an armature is (they are bones) so I can't animated my character.

I searched everywhere on Youtube but I don't find anyone fix this problem.

In this image I just select the rig rigify generated with the armature, as you can see the rig is just like my armature except for the jaw

[image: In this image I just select the rig rigify generated with the armature, as you can see the rig is just like my armature except for the jaw]

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid we need more details than that! For a start, what are you actually trying to use Rigify on? - Without any images or being able to look at your Blend file it's impossible to help you.  You can share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/ if it's under 30Meg in size following the instructions there to copy the link to your question into the field on that page and it will then appear in your question.

Comment: Have you looked how to use Rigify to begin with? It looks like you customized the metarig with no regards to how it actually works. You can't just create any bones you want and have Rigify figure out what they each are supposed to generate, you need to use premade limbs or create and define new ones using Rigify's way of functioning. There are plenty of tutorials online to generate custom rigs with Rigify, you can also look at [Rigify - Advanced Usage — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html#advanced-usage)

Comment: @JohnEason The blender file is to big even with unnecessary things ... I add a photo of what I try to rigify . Can you tell me what informations do you need because I don t know what should i give you . Also is the file with just the armature will help you because i think the file will be under 30 Meg . Thank you !

Comment: @L0Lock Yes , I watch many tutorials on YouTube and I just use a Human rig for my rigging . Then I add samples like a jaw , a simple chain , and a tongue so everything come from rigify . If you want anything more just tell me and I will answer you ! Thank you !

Comment: Have you seen CG Dive's [series](https://youtu.be/ERAScO1s8Zk) on rigging anything with Rigify? - That would be my first stop!

Comment: [Rigify doesn't have either of a "jaw", "tongue" nor "simple chain"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html#rigify-rig-samples). There is a "faces.super_face" sample that provides an entire face's rig, but you can't pick apart bits of it: it's all or nothing. A blend file would be much appreciated. Only your metarig is theoretically needed, so no need to include anything else if it makes it impossible to upload on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnEason No I never watched these videos of CG Dive's but I have seen others . But I'll hurry to watch the serie If I can see one thing I missed ! Also I shared my amrature with blender exchange , if you want to take a look . Thank you !

Comment: @L0Lock I have seen someone who did this with is character rigging (import several samples and parent them to the head bone ) and It work pretty good in his case . I will try to take the jaw that Rigify gives me with the armature but my character need a custom armature for his hands and for the straw he wear on his head . Also I shared my armature like you asked for , if you want to take a look at it . Thank You !

Comment: You'll have to include the link provided on the blend-exchange page in your question otherwise there's no way for use to download your blend file!

Comment: @JohnEason I m sorry i am new and they ask me for the link of my question so i thought it was automatically exchange somewhere in the page . Now it s good

Comment: Ok. It's now downloading ok, but as @L0Lock says there's no way that Rigify is going to be able to make sense of the mess of bones that you have in your armature. To be honest I wouldn't even know where to begin to improve matters. :^(

Comment: Yes I see the problem and I think just follow the videos you share to have a correct armature even if it mean that i do not use samples for my jaw and other things . If you have anything just tell me and i would be glad to answer you ! Thank you for your time both of you and if it's work I'll let you know !

Comment: I have to apologize, I didn't stay updated enough about Rigify x) Turns out since v3.0 a few more rig types were added, including ones for the jaw and tongue. Source: [Rig Types — Blender Manual 3.6](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/index.html). Regardless, there are quite a few issues in your rig that need fixing to make it work. I am writing an answer, though I will have to leave for a couple of hours very soon, so it will take a while to post my final answer. But it will come!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Preamble

I have to take back some words:

> [Rigify doesn't have either of a "jaw", "tongue" nor "simple chain"](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.81/addons/rigging/rigify.html#rigify-rig-samples). There is a "faces.super_face" sample that provides an entire face's rig, but you can't pick apart bits of it: it's all or nothing.

This was back in v2.81. In the current 3.61 we do have move rig types for facials in Rigify:

> - [Faces](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/faces.html)
>
>   - [`faces.super_face`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/faces.html#faces-super-face)
> - [Skin](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html)
>
>   - [`skin.basic_chain`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html#skin-basic-chain)
>   - [`skin.stretchy_chain`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html#skin-stretchy-chain)
>   - [`skin.anchor`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html#skin-anchor)
>   - [`skin.glue`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html#skin-glue)
>   - [`skin.transform.basic`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/skin.html#skin-transform-basic)
> - [Face](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/face.html)
>
>   - [`face.basic_tongue`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/face.html#face-basic-tongue)
>   - [`face.skin_eye`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/face.html#face-skin-eye)
>   - [`face.skin_jaw`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/face.html#face-skin-jaw)
>
> ---
>
> Source: [Rig Types — Blender Manual 3.6](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/index.html)

All the items in the "skin" and "face" categories were added back in v3.0 as part of the new standard face rig for Rigify: [#89808 - Adopting a new standard face rig for Rigify - blender-addons - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender-addons/issues/89808)

---

A few issues in your rig that make things go wrong: the orientation of the armature, the rig types declaration, and a few things about general rules of rigging. Let's go through them:

### Armature Orientation

If you select your armature in Object Mode and look at its rotation, you will see it rotated 180⁰:

[image]

This means, even though it looks like your armature is facing the front side of the world, it is actually facing the back side. If you set it back to 0⁰, you would see what the armature really looks like.
And therefore, when you generate the Rigify rig, the result is the face controllers facing backwards:

[image]

With your armature facing forward, select it in object mode, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Apply Rotation. This will set the current rotation as the new zero rotation.

If you generate the rig again, it faces the correct direction:

[image]

But now you should notice most your limbs are missing from the generated rig, which leads us to rig types declaration.

### Rig Type Declaration

As you can read in its documentation, Rigify uses rig types to identify what is in the metarig and what to do with them.

Right now, aside from your facial elements, none of the bones in your metarig have rig types, hence they don't generate anything.

If you add another metarig in your scene, <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into Pose Mode and select any first parent of a bone chain (I.E. `thigh.L`), you can see in the Properties Editor > Bone data tab > Rigify Type panel a bunch of information and settings:

[image]

The Rig Type is what tells rigify what the chain is supposed to be, and the settings bellow it depend on the rig type and will influence the rig generation. No rig type, and the chain is ignored.

If you look at your rig's `thigh.L`, there's nothing set up:

[image]

Plus, some of the bones you have are incorrectly placed: Feet are too high, fingers are twisted and don't have a slight curvature to let the IK system know in which way they must bend, ...

[image]

You can fix this two ways:

1. manually declare the rig types and their settings for each chain (thighs, fingers, spine, arms, etc) by copying the settings from a clean default metarig, then fix your bones twisting and placements.
2. Delete all bones except the facial ones that work, add a new clean metarig, delete all its facial bones, join the old metarig object into the new one, and rearrange their position to your model.

Since you are not familiar with Rigify, I would suggest the last option, as it should be the most foolproof:

1. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode and select only your custom facial bones, hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to invert your selection, and <kbd>X</kbd> > Delete Bones.
2. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into object mode. Press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Add Armature > Human (Meta-Rig).
3. Tab into edit mode to select and delete the facial bones. That includes the `face` bone, but not the `spine.xxx` bones:
   [image]
4. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> back to object mode, select the old metarig, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select the new metarig, and press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join the selected objects to the last selected. Some of your bones will disappear: that's because they were on layers that the default metarig doesn't show right now:
   [image]
   You can simply <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> these two layers to display them.
5. <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> into edit mode, now is a good time to give your custom bone a proper name instead of just "Bone". To make sure your facial bones are all on the same and correct default layer, select them all, hit M and click the first layer as they should be:
   [image]

If you generate a rig at this point (I just scaled down the body's bones in edit mode so to fit them to the facial bones level), it will look like this:

[image]

Now all that's left is to move the bones to adapt them to your rig,

A few things to keep in mind:

- bones must face the same direction. You shouldn't rotate them on their local Y axe. You can turn on the armature's Axes display in Properies Editor > Armature tab > Viewport Display panel > Axes.
- IK chains (like fingers, spine, etc) need to be bent in a single direction so that the IK solver knows which way it is supposed to bend. That's why kneed are a little forward and elbows a little backwards. You must to the same for the fingers and spine. If you bend them in the wrong direction or multiple axes, you will get unexpected results when moving IK controllers.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and for solving my problem ! I don’t know how to thank you enough ! I think I’ll should go back to study more . What you taught me is precious and I keep in mind this lesson for the future !

Comment: Just take it slow. Baby steps get you far ;)